# php json_decode not working for large string

Tags: php

can anyone please help me to sort out `json_decode` issue , here is my json string which is working fine -

```
{"323":"723","317":"704","316": {"date":"28\/12\/2016"},"314":"701","315": {"area":"sdfgdfg"}}
```

but if I add one more key value pair then json_decode function does not work.

```
{"336":"761","323":"723","317":"704","316": {"date":"28\/12\/2016"},"314":"701","315": {"area":"test"}}
```

2nd string is not working , however at my local system both strings are working fine , what are the php config parameters I need to check ? I have increase **memory limit** , **max execution time** and **max post size** what else I need to check , please help.

**updated** here are my codes -

```
$arrProducts = array(
        array(
            "product_id" => $_REQUEST['product_id'],
            "qty" => $_REQUEST['quantity'],
            "options" => json_decode($_REQUEST['product_options'], true),
            "sku" => $_REQUEST['sku'],
            "store_id" => 1
        )
    );
print_r($arrProducts);
```

it prints blank array for the 2nd string.

I have checked error log , it shows - **PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 274 bytes exceeds the limit of 256 bytes in Unknown on line 0**

Comment: could you please provide the code in question, too? i'm guessing it has nothing to do with json_decode itself.

Comment: Check for errors using [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: Your second string decodes without any problems: https://eval.in/701965

Comment: Unable to replicate any issues - `json_decode` on the above string works fine.

Comment: can you include your php code

Comment: You should add the results of `var_dump($_REQUEST['product_options']);`. That is probably not the same as the string you posted.

Comment: @RamRaider - as I mentioned both strings are working fine at my local PC but not at my server , so what php configurations I need to check , thank you.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by "does not work". What does your http servers error log file say? What does the function actually return? What is the difference between the two situations?

Comment: can you `var_dump($_REQUEST['product_options']);`

Comment: @NewbeeDev - sure , I am updating it.

Comment: @NewbeeDev - it is printing NULL when print var_dump($_REQUEST['product_options']);

Comment: if that's not working only in your live server then try checking your apache error log in your live

Comment: it says - PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 274 bytes exceeds the limit of 256 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the question is misleading,
  the issue that you are facing is not that json_decode fails to decode rather the POST maximum size is exceeding

You may find something like the following in your  `php.ini` file

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 256
```

Change the above to

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

ie, 8M as post size limit

And if you are using apache you may need to change .htaccess aswell.
Here is the reference for  [#post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: actually I was not able to debug it , thank you , it is working now.