# json_decode returns null for valid twitter json

Tags: php, json

Tried a bunch of solutions, including just copy/pasting a json response into a string to see why `json_decode` fails. (And checking for BOM, slashes, etc)

However, I don't understand why this valid json always returns null for json_decode.

Note - larger data set than usual provided in the string. Typically the string is less than 60kb.

https://gist.github.com/yosun/9cfb4bdf1e912600ab9d63d0021e4197

Comment: Unquoted quote at 451. Did you run it through a JSON checker?

Comment: can you see any error ?

Comment: according to PHP manual "NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit" http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258189/php-json-decode-not-working-for-large-string

Comment: Have you tried using `json_last_error` for debugging `json_decode`? http://php.net/json_last_error